# Application of ST_DISTANCE in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Based on the the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_distance), I am attempting to calulcate the distance between two coordinates. Both coordinates are formatted as strings and follow the syntax (*Latitude Value* *Longitude Value*) (see screenshot). However, when I attempt to query as follows:

```
SELECT  ride_id, ST_DISTANCE(start_station_location, end_station_location, FALSE) FROM `cyclistic-case.Tripdata.all_rides_final` LIMIT 10
```

I am told that there is an error

> No matching signature for function ST_DISTANCE for argument types: STRING, STRING, BOOL. Supported signature: ST_DISTANCE(GEOGRAPHY, GEOGRAPHY, [BOOL]) at [3:1

Can anyone please help me in figuring out where my error is?

[Screenshot location syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVadA.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the locations are around Chicago, rather than South Pole, the coordinates you have seem to follow pattern

```
(latitude longitude)
```

BigQuery uses WKT with syntax for points `POINT(longitude latitude)`. Note the order is different. It can also understand GeoJson, but again the order is longitude first, latitude second.

What you can do, following Samuel pattern of creating an extract function, is something like the code below. It splits the strings on space (`SPLIT` call), and then discards extra characters (`TRIM` call), and uses `ST_GEOGPOINT` to construct the Geography point, note we pass second coordinate (longitude) first, first coordinate (latitude) second:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  ST_StringToGeo(str String) AS (
      ST_GEOGPOINT(
          CAST(TRIM(SPLIT(str, ' ')[ORDINAL(2)], "()") AS FLOAT64),
          CAST(TRIM(SPLIT(str, ' ')[ORDINAL(1)], "()") AS FLOAT64)
      ));
```

Comment: how did you guess that I had in fact meant Chicago rather than the South Pole? ;)
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Just looked at the coordinates in screenshot. Lat of -87 is too close to South Pole, so I made a guess lat and lon are mixed up (as is extremely common).

Comment: no, that was more sarcasm. You are quite obviously right that I don't care so much about coordinates at the South Pole but more about those in Chicago. As you pointed out, I made the common mistake of mixing up latitude with longitude when appying ST_DISTANCE. Rookie mistake but it was also the very first time I had to deal with ST_DISTANCE. Having done that, though, will hopefully prevent me from repeating that mistake (or notice this mistake myslelf, at least). So thanks a lot for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

The text of the coordinates have to be parsed first. Thank you all for a correction help!

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ST_stringtogeo(str String)
    AS (ST_GEOGFROMTEXT(CONCAT("POINT(", 
        SPLIT(replace(str,")","")," ")[offset(1)]," ",
        substr(SPLIT(str," ")[offset(0)],2),")"
        ))); #

SELECT
  ride_id,
  ST_DISTANCE(ST_stringtogeo(start_station_location),ST_stringtogeo(end_station_location), FALSE) as distance
FROM
(select 5 as ride_id, "(41.973815 -87.65966)" as start_station_location, "(41.93758231600629 -87.6440978050232)" as end_station_location)
  #`cyclistic-case.Tripdata.all_rides_final`
```

Comment: thanks but this was not a hyphen but a minus sign in front of the longitude part of the coordinate. It is a vital element of it and cannot be removed.

Comment: Thank you @HerrSan, is there a space before the minus sign? If yes, it should work now. I removed the replacement of the `-`

Comment: Assuming the locations are around Chicago, rather than South Pole, the coordinates also needs to be swapped - BigQuery WKT uses longitude first, latitude second, while it seems to be the opposite order here.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelEntin ! You are right, the two coordinated have to be swapped.